# How to create a query on 2 existing tables and build a table(view) with data from both tables and a condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

sorry the title might be a little bit confusing.
I will try to explain in full here and add some tables as examples.
Ok, what I have is  a MS-SQL database that I use to store data/info coming from equipments that are mounted in some vehicles.
For the moment there are 2 tables in the database: "Communication" - a big table Used to store every information from the equipments when they connect to the TCP-server. Records are added one after another (only INSERTS here).
The table looks like this:
 [image]

The second table "EquipmentStatus" - it has EquipmentID as a primary key, so it is a smaller table (only UPDATES here), and it looks like this:
[image]

Well, what I would need is a new table with Vehicles that DID communicate between Date_1 and Date_2,  i.e. a **SQL query that can provide this**:
[image]
where Date_1 and Date_2 have been set to 20 respectively 22 of June).

Also, the next step would be to get also a table(view) for Vehicles that DID NOT communicate between Date_1 and Date_2, i.e. the one you see below:
[image]

Thanks for your time and patience!

Comment: You can use sql-server functions to represent the two tables/views you need, which can take two parameters (start and end date) and provide you the dynamic result. You can query the two functions directly, just like tables

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that date of last communication should be in the given range [Date_1 ... Date_2]  obviously...  Mea culpa!

Answer (score 2):

I took a stab at these without having the data on my end, but this should get you on the right path.

A:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.Vehicle_Number, s.Vehicle_Status, s.DateLastCommunication
FROM EquipmentStatus s
INNER JOIN Communications c
ON s.Equipment_ID = c.Equipment_ID
WHERE c.DateTimeCommunication BETWEEN '2015-06-20' AND '2015-06-22'
```

B:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.Vehicle_Number, s.Vehicle_Status, s.DateLastCommunication
FROM EquipmentStatus s
INNER JOIN Communications c
ON s.Equipment_ID = c.Equipment_ID
WHERE s.Equipment_ID NOT IN 
    (SELECT Equipment_ID FROM Communications WHERE DateTimeCommunication
    BETWEEN '2015-06-20' AND '2015-06-22')
```

Answer (score 2):

is this what you are looking for?

```
declare @startDate datetime, @enddate datetime

--vehicles communicated
select A.Vehicle_Number, b.Vehicle_Status, A.DataLastCommunication
from (
Select Vehicle_Number, MAX(DataLastCommunication) as DataLastCommunication
from dbo.Communications
where DataLastCommunication between @startDate and @enddate
group by Vehicle_Number
) as A
  inner join dbo.EquipmentStatus b
      on a.Vehicle_Number=b.Vehicle_Number 
         and a.DataLastCommunication = b.DataLastCommunication    


--vehicles did not communicate
select a.Vehicle_Number, a.Vehicle_Status, a.DataLastCommunication
from dbo.EquipmentStatus a
where not exists(
  select 1 
  from dbo.Communications
  where Vehicle_Number=a.Vehicle_Number
    and DataLastCommunication between @startDate and @enddate
)
```

The last query should use a Vehicles table instead of the communications table because it could be possible that there is a new vehicle which has no entries yet in any of these 2 tables (which will return the vehicle number but the status and date will be null)....

Comment: I will definitely try these tomorrow (it's 0:45am here :)... I didn't know about MAX() availability :) Hope it'll work. Thanks, keep in touch!

Comment: sure...just let me know if I made a wrong assumption or misunderstood your requirement...if yes, we can always fix it...no issues..cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

In sql-server, you can use functions to return the two different set of data, just like two new tables:

```
create function f_has_comm(@date1 datetime, @date2 datetime)
returns table
as
return (select Vehicle_Number, Vehical_status, DateLastCommunication 
    from EquipmentStatus where EquipmentID in (select EquipmentID from Communication 
        where DatetimeCommunication>=@date1 and DatetimeCommunication<=@date2)
    )

go

create function f_no_comm(@date1 datetime, @date2 datetime)
returns table
as
return (select Vehicle_Number, Vehical_status, DateLastCommunication 
    from EquipmentStatus where EquipmentID NOT IN (select EquipmentID from Communication 
        where DatetimeCommunication>=@date1 and DatetimeCommunication<=@date2)
    )

go
```

and now you can select from the two functions like:

```
 select * from f_has_comm('2015-6-1','2015-6-20');
 select * from f_no_comm('2015-6-1','2015-6-20');
```